# Customizing Parse Log in with background image (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Because Parse handles Logging In so well, I want to stick with Parse's default Log In/Sign Up screen which I present over a blank viewController.

However, to customize it more I'd like to add (preferably blurred) background image behind the Log In/Sign up text fields and buttons.

I can place the blurred image in a View via the Storyboard, but how can I set the background of the logInViewController that I pop so the background image is visible?

Alternatively, how could place the blurred background image via a call on LogInViewController?  So far I haven't been able to do exactly what I'm trying to do.  My code below adds the image as a patternImage, but I want it to take up the entire screen's background.

func showLogInViewController() {

```
        //build logInVC in Code:
        var logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()

        var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()

        logInLogoTitle.text = "Thredz"

        logInLogoTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Cochin", size: 40.0)

        logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword     | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.Twitter //| PFLogInFields.Facebook

        logInViewController.logInView?.logo = logInLogoTitle

        logInViewController.logInView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "SFStreetcar")!)

        logInViewController.delegate = self

        //present log in VC
        self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out a solution:

```
logInViewController.logInView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

loginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```

...results in the Parse Log In being overlayed over the imageView I set up in my storyboard.